# MS Access - Query Definition Disappears After VBA Executes

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 database that I set up to keep track of time at work. I have a button on a form with the following VBA:

```
Private Sub cmdExport_Click()
Dim myUser As String

myUser = Environ("Username")

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "ExportTime", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "C:\Users\" & myUser & "\Desktop\Time" & Format(Me.txtStartDate, "yyyymmdd") & "-" & Format(Me.txtEndDate, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint

End Sub
```

The button exports a saved query named ExportTime with the following definition:

```
SELECT MYTIME.MYDATE, MYTIME.ID, MYTIME.CM, MYTIME.MYDESCRIP, MYTIME.MYHOURS
FROM CM RIGHT JOIN MYTIME ON CM.ID = MYTIME.CM
WHERE (((MYTIME.MYDATE)>=[Forms]![ExportTime]![txtStartDate] And (MYTIME.MYDATE)<=[Forms]![ExportTime]![txtEndDate]))
ORDER BY MYTIME.MYDATE, MYTIME.CM;
```

Pressing the button successfully exports the time to an Excel spreadsheet, exactly as I intend it to.

The problem is that after running this operation, the query definition disappears.  The named query is still in the list of saved queries, but its definition is changed to just

```
SELECT;
```

This seems to happen regularly. I’ve copied the query definition to a text file, so I can paste it back in when I want to export my time again. I’m stumped as to why the definition keeps disappearing, though.

Any thoughts or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the definition get reset immediately after the cmdExport_Click sub exits? Or is it after the form exits? is there any other code at play here? This certainly is odd.

Comment: Does it happen regularly with just this database, or any databases you use this code in?  I've seen some quirks like this with corrupt Access databases, but compact and repair usually helps.

Comment: Of course now that I posted this I can't seem to replicate the problem.  It happened again this morning, which is when I finally got fed up and posted here.  I will try again tomorrow morning and see if it happens again. I don't think there is any other code at play. This is a pretty lightweight db that I made just for myself. And I don't use this code in any other databases. Thanks Brad and Jimmy both for responding. I will comment again if I can replicate the problem. I have never done compact and repair on this db.  I will try that if the problem crops up again.

Comment: The problem occurred again. Since posting I had been unable to replicate the problem. I had run compact and repair, and thought that fixed the problem. But on Friday the query definition disappeared again. I opened the ExportTime form and clicked the button and received an error message. The query definition was "SELECT;". The only code on the form from which I run the query is the "cmdExport_Click" vba described above. There’s no other code in the database that refers to the ExportTime query. I fixed it by pasting the query definition back in. But I don’t know why it disappears to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I use saved export specifications to accomplish this task and in VBA :

```
CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications("<name of export specification>").Execute False
```

I'm not sure whether a query in this case can refer to form fields; I copy the values into TempVars and that works.